# Making one input as required based on the input of another key

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I am using [JOI](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) for schema validation. In the following schema, I want `input_file` to be of type required when `type` is `jobType.MBR`, otherwise `file_name` must remain of type `required`

```
const jobObjectSchema = {
  type: Joi.string().valid(jobType.MBR, jobType.MP4).required(),
  file_name: Joi.string().required(),
  input_file: Joi.string()
};
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Joi` `any().when`.

```
const jobObjectSchema = {
  type: Joi.string().valid(jobType.MBR, jobType.MP4).required(),
  file_name: Joi.any().when('type', {
    is: jobType.MBR, 
    then: Joi.string().optional(),
    otherwise: Joi.string().required()
  }),
  input_file: Joi.any().when('type', {
    is: jobType.MBR, 
    then: Joi.string().required(),
    otherwise: Joi.string().optional()
  })
};
```